# Is it possible to add an svg element to an open layers map with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, openlayers-3

I have an open layers map that I am trying to add an SVG legend to. Is it possible to do this with d3.js?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom control like in this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/custom-controls.html).

```
app.Legend = function(opt_options) {

  var options = opt_options || {};

  // create an element with your SVG legend
  var legend = document.createElement(...);
  // ...

  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'ol-control';
  element.appendChild(legend);

  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });

};
ol.inherits(app.Legend, ol.control.Control);

map.addControl(new app.Legend());
```